# How do i fetch data from firebase , i am getting an error saying uid is null, even though the user is logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am also using getStaticprops from next.js.
I am trying to fetch data , I am following the code on firebase documentation, but i keep running into a error
[image]

```js
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=4"
  );
  const images = await res.json();
  console.log(auth.currentUser);

  //
  const userRef = ref(database, "users/" + auth.currentUser.uid);

  onValue(userRef, (snapshot) => {
    const properties = snapshot.val();
    console.log(properties);
  });
  //

  return {
    props: {
      images,
      properties,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you show the content of `auth.currentUser`?

Comment: Possibly `auth.currentUser` is `null`.Make sure your `currentUser` is not null.

Comment: it says null, but I am logged in

Comment: Where does `auth.currentUser` come from? Can you share the code where that comes from?